# How to use acronym package with beamer

Tags: beamer, acronyms

For a beamer based presentation I'd like to reuse some figures/tables/diagrams I created in a paper.
These figures/tables/diagrams are stored in dedicated files so that I could work on them individually (reducing compilation time and having always an MWE).

So it's rather easy to inlcude these into the presentation. In the paper I used the "acronym" package to manage acronyms which requires a dedicated section where used acronyms are shown (acronym definitions are also in an external files, because of sorting). I'd like to avoid that the acronym definitions have to appear but it seems that this breaks the figures/tables/diagrams which use the acronyms.

Adding the acronym section solves the issue with the acronyms but does not look nice.
"Hiding" the page with the acronyms does not really work either...
(In the MWE the acronym the is used in the frametitle as an example but they could be anywhere.)

Any ideas:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{An institute}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
% this would work but shows the acronyms
%\begin{frame}
%    \begin{acronym}[~~~~]
%        \acro{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
%        \acused{TLA}
%    \end{acronym}
%\end{frame}
% this hides the acronym page but doesn't work otherwise
\begin{frame}<presentation:0>[noframenumbering]
    \begin{acronym}[~~~~]
        \acro{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
        \acused{TLA}
    \end{acronym}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\ac{TLA} used here}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `\acrodef` in the preamble instead of `\acro` inside of an `aycronym` environment and `\acs` instead of `\ac` should result in the expected output.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{acronym}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{An institute}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\acrodef{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\acs{TLA} used here}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That‘s exactly what I would like to avoid. I would have to touch all occurrences in all files. I‘d rather prefer to „just include“ the existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @leandriis answer using acrodef I came up with this solution.

It seems that the `\acro` macro is only available in the `acronym` environement so `\newcommand` is used instead of `\renewcommand` to map it to `acrodef`.
Why not use `\acrodef` directly? All the `\acro` definitions are already inside an external file. Redefining the command avoids changing the shared file.

Since `\acused` can be used anywhere, one can mock the acronym to have been used as in the paper. Using the `\acused` command forces the short version for the specific acronym used later on.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{acronym}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{An institute}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\newcommand{\acro}[2]{\acrodef{#1}{#2}}
\acro{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
\acused{TLA}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\ac{TLA} used here}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```